# How to write AWS Code pipeline only for updated files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I am very new to AWS.

I have task where I need to write Code pipeline to copy files from CodeCommit to S3 bucket, but condition is only update/deleted files should get copied. I have already written pipeline, but it copies all the files to S3 bucket.

I tried writing AWS Lambda + Python code, but it works the same. I used below chunk of code,

https://medium.com/@michael.niedermayr/using-aws-codecommit-and-lambda-for-automatic-code-deployment-to-s3-bucket-b35aa83d029b

Any help or suggestion appreciated

Comment: Super interesting for me. Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the S3 deploy action to copy your files, use a CodeBuild action in your CodePipeline.

In the CodeBuild buildspec, use '[aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)' command with the '--delete' switch to sync files to the S3 bucket. Make sure the CodeBuild Service role has permission to write to the S3 bucket.

Comment: I did, but it gives same issue. It still copying all files. I used below chunk of code in buildspec   build:
    commands:
       - aws s3 sync . s3://mys3bucket --delete